# Check a value in a String matches an element in an array C# unity,

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am trying to check if the value in string word from one class matches any element in the array stringAnswers in another and if it does i want the score to increment by 1. For some reason the code im using below increments the score by 1,2 and 3 depending on the word that is displayed any help would be awesome cheers.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int Score = 0;

    private string[] StringAns = {"steve", "grace", "lilly"};

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.GetComponent<ButtonNo>()  != null)
                {
                    foreach (string stringAnsers in StringAns)
                    {

                        if (stringAnsers.Equals(FindObjectOfType<GameController>().word))
                        {
                            Debug.Log(" Button has been looked at");
                            FindObjectOfType<GameController>().RandText();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Debug.Log(" Button has been looked at");
                            FindObjectOfType<GameController>().RandText();

                            Score++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.GetComponent<ButtonYes>() != null)
                {
                    foreach (string stringAnsers in StringAns)
                    {
                        if (stringAnsers.Equals( FindObjectOfType<GameController>().word) )
                        {
                            Debug.Log(" Button has been looked at");
                            FindObjectOfType<GameController>().RandText();

                            Score++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            FindObjectOfType<GameController>().RandText();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GameController**

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public TextMesh InfoText;
    public TextMesh WallText;
    public string word;
    public Player player;

    public string[] Strings = { "stev", "lilly", "grace" };

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        RandText();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        InfoText.text = "Is this Spelling Correct ?\n Score: " + player.Score;
    }

    public void RandText()
    {
         word = Strings[Random.Range(0, Strings.Length)];

        WallText = GameObject.Find("WallText").GetComponent<TextMesh>();
        WallText.text = word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general you should call `FindObjectOfType<GameController>()` only once e.g in Start

```
private GameController _gameController;

private void Start()
{
    _gameController= FindObjectOfType<GameController>();
}
```

and than reuse that `_gameController` reference everywhere instead of `FindObjectOfType<GameController>()`.

The same for `WallText` in `GameController`:

```
public TextMesh WallText;

private void Start()
{
    WallText = GameObject.Find("WallText").GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    RandText();
}

public void RandText()
{
    word = Strings[Random.Range(0, Strings.Length)];
    WallText.text = word;
}
```

better would even be you already reference those in the Inspector in Unity via drag&drop than you don't have to use `Find` at all

---

**Than to your problem:** You are setting a new value for `word` in every iteration for the loop

```
foreach (string stringAnsers in StringAns)
{
    if (stringAnsers.Equals(FindObjectOfType<GameController>().word))
    {
        Debug.Log("Button has been looked at");
        FindObjectOfType<GameController>().RandText();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Button has been looked at");
        FindObjectOfType<GameController>().RandText();

        Score++;
    }
}
```

So it might happen that the word doesn't match so you call `Score++;` but at the same time you do `FindObjectOfType<GameController>().RandText();` everytime so a new random word is generated/selected for each iteration.

So in the next iteration of the foreach loop you check against a new random word which might or might not match the next answer string in the list.

---

Instead you should only generate a new random word **after** the loop is done e.g. like

```
foreach (string stringAnsers in StringAns)
{
    if (stringAnsers.Equals(FindObjectOfType<GameController>().word))
    {
        Debug.Log("Button has been looked at-> matched");
        Score++;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Button has been looked at -> didn't match");
    }
}

FindObjectOfType<GameController>().RandText();
```

Note this would still add `1-3` points depending how many of the given `stringAnswer` match the word. So you should add a `break;` after increasing `Score` once if you want only `1` added.

---

Using Linq you could also do this in only one line instead a loop:

```
if(StringAns.Any(answer => string.Equals(answer, _gameController.word)))) Score++;

_gameController.RandText();
```

or for the `No` button

```
if(!StringAns.Any(answer => string.Equals(answer, _gameController.word)))) Score++;
```

Comment: Sorry first time on here and I missed a bit out, I have 2 objects as cubes which are yes and no buttons so to speak of. so if the player gets the correct answer the score increments by one and then a new random word from the array strings is displayed

Comment: yes ... and I adressed that telling you that currently you select a new random list for each stringAnswer so they are probbably all compared to different random words. move the `RandText` **after** the loop and either add the `break` keyword after increasing the `Score` or use the Linq solution at the bottom

Comment: It seem to work but for some real strange reason, the word grace and lilly give boths a score for yes and no so i think there is something wrong when matching the strings

Comment: The linq version you gave works a treat so thank you very much for that but Because i like to solve problems im going to have to find out why the other way doesnt .

Comment: @SteveDeeks well it depends what is in your `StringAns` ... if all three names are allways there than there will be allways one of them matching the random word

Comment: Thats the bit I don't get cause I have deliberately made one of the words which will appear as a random word, wrong, so it should not match anything in the answer array

Comment: so wait, as I understood you want: Yes button: +1 point if any of the answers matches. No button: +1 if none of the asnwers matches. right?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, What I would like is If the yes button is pressed the string word is checked against the answer array if there is a match then score +1 but if the player press no on the same word there is no score but similarly if there is a incorrect spell in the string word and the no button is press it also gives a score +1 and if yes is press then there is no score

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are generating a new random word inside the foreach loop that check the word itself. Also, i suggest you not to use a foreach loop, because items inside the array could be more that 3 items, so it could slow the method. I suggest you to use `contains` instead, like so:

```
if (StringAns.Contains(FindObjectOfType<GameController>().word))
{
      Debug.Log(" Button has been looked at");
      Score++;
}
else
      Debug.Log(" Button has *not* been looked at");

FindObjectOfType<GameController>().RandText();
```